# Get custom type data from Oracle using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have troubles with getting my data to Java from Oracle DB. Instead of real value, only 3 question marks are returned from database.

First i created my type as follows:

```
create or replace TYPE varchar2_ntt AS VARRAY(5000) OF varchar2(200);
```

Then I wrote my sql:

```
SELECT del.stop_name AS direction,
  del.departures
FROM
  (SELECT mvv.STOP_NAME,
    mvv.stop_id,
    CAST( COLLECT(SUBSTR(departure_time,1,5)
  ORDER BY departure_time) AS varchar2_ntt ) departures
  FROM stop_times st,
    MV_TRIP_V_SMER mvv,
    trips t
  LEFT JOIN calendar c
  ON c.service_id= t.service_id,
    routes r,
    mv_rezimi_za_postajni_vr pvr
  WHERE mvv.trip_id =st.trip_id
  AND st.trip_id    =t.TRIP_ID
  AND r.route_id    =t.route_id
  AND pvr.service_id=c.service_id
  AND pvr.workday=1
  AND st.stop_id    ='2206100000201'
  GROUP BY mvv.STOP_NAME,
    mvv.stop_id
  ) DEL
```

result for column departures in sql developer looks fine.

```
SHEMA.VARCHAR2_NTT('13:15','16:25','18:15','19:45')
```

In Java im trying to get the results:

```
while (rs.next()){
    ARRAY departures_a =((OracleResultSet)rs).getARRAY("departures");
    System.out.println ("Array is of type "+departures_a.getSQLTypeName());
    System.out.println ("Array is of length "+departures_a.length());
    String[] departures_arr = (String[]) departures_a.getArray();
    for (int n=0; n<departures_arr.length; n++){
         System.out.println("departure "+n+":"+ departures_arr[n]);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Array is of type SHEMA.VARCHAR2_NTT
Array is of length 4
departure 0:???
departure 1:???
departure 2:???
departure 3:???
```

What im doing wrong? Why there are question marks instead of real values?

I found instructions
[here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22034) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/samapp4.htm#1011963).

Comment: This works for me ("pure JDBC", no Oracle classes):  `Array ar = rs.getArray("departures");String[] elements = (String[])ar.getArray();`

Comment: Works for me with Oracle classes too, using your code; 11.2.0.3, ojdbc6.jar (and 5 and 7). Are you using an incompatible driver version perhaps? What data type is `departure_time`?

Comment: Yes it works with pure JDBC, I tried both but there is no difference.

Comment: I have driver version 11.2.0.1. My database is "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production"
Departure time is varchar2

Comment: It's still possible my version of Oracle driver is incopatible since i have some troubles with export utility sometimes. Dont know which error, but if i google it people usual say its drivers fault...
But I dont have enough time for research now, deadline is too close, I will make a workaround without custom types.

Comment: What problems do you get with `orai18n.jar` in the classpath? Try to print the exception (toString()) instead of (getMessage()). Which character set you are using in the database and on the machine where you run the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a charset problem. Try to print the result you receive.

```
System.out.printf("departure %d: %s%n", i, Arrays.toString(departures[i].getBytes()));
```

Print also the typecode

```
System.out.println("Array element is of typecode " + departures_a.getBaseType());
```

Comment: i dont think its charset problem. No matter what the result is, I always get ??? (even if string is 100 chars long).
I tried your code, output was "departure 0: [?, ?, ?]" and so on

Comment: Sorry I meant to get the bytes.

Comment: this might be a charset problem. I recall something similar when using Advanced queueing. The solution was to add one more .jar file into classpath - aside from ojdbc7.jar. This library had something to do with charset converions.

Comment: Maybe solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435950/jdbc-array-binding-character-set-encoding. Add orai18n.jar into your classpath.

Comment: orai18n.jar caused me troubles. I couldn't connect to the database when I added it to classpath (ex.getMessage returned null). On this project we still use use java 6, so im using ojdbc6.
@SubOptimal: Output for typecode: "Array element is of typecode 12"
Ouput for getBytes(): "departure 0: [63, 63, 63]"
Nothnig useful :S

Comment: @ibre5041 thank you, I experienced the same problem once again. Adding  orai18n.jar to the classpath solved the problem this time.